# Connecting to IOCP server in Java (Android)

Tags: java, android, client, iocp

I'd like to make an Online Game with Android.

I'm planning to make Server with IOCP model via C++. This should work fine, the problem is the client.
IOCP client example in C++ uses `WSASyncselect` or `WSAEventSelect`.

I couldn't find any Java examples that same work like async socket.

**Questions:**

1. Is there anything like `WSASyncselect()` in Java?
2. If not that, how could i do it?

Answer (score 3):

The JDK 7 Windows implementation of the Java 7 "NIO.2" classes

- [AsynchronousSocketChannel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/AsynchronousSocketChannel.html)
- [AsynchronousServerSocketChannel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/AsynchronousServerSocketChannel.html)
- [AsynchronousFileChannel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/AsynchronousFileChannel.html)

  call the WSA[...] functions of the [Windows "Overlapped IO" API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overlapped_I/O) behind the scenes.

For more in-depth information check out the OpenJDK repository folders containing [the implementation .java sources](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/tl-gate/jdk/file/d7ed56d57d97/src/windows/classes/sun/nio/ch/) along with their corresponding [.c native sources and JNI bindings](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/tl-gate/jdk/file/d7ed56d57d97/src/windows/native/sun/nio/ch/)
.