# Connecting non-IOCP client with IOCP Server

Tags: c++, sockets, iocp

I am designing a client-server application. 
My server will be in C++ and using IOCP for TCP/IP communication.

Decision for technology for client development not decided yet. So I have few questions regarding IOCP compatibility with client to be developed in future (I need to freeze design for Server):

1. Can I use general socket programming of java(client will be developed in java more likely) to communicate IOCP based Server?
2. How IOCP responds for abrupt and graceful termination of client connection (what notification I'll get on server)?

Thanks

Nipun

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are talking about socket programming here, and the middle layer is TCP/IP and so the network programming library (e.g. IOCP) is irrelevant.  You can use whatever language or library on the client side.

Comment: True, but that does not mean it's easy to do. It's like saying CORBA is just TCP. Depending on how advanced the IOCP library is, it may be very hard to reverse engineer it.

Comment: @Prof.Falken That's.. not what Hei said. The IOCP server still uses the TCP/IP protocol to communicate with clients, the fact that it uses IOCP technology is irrelevant to the client and is an implementation detail. The client can connect to it by digital carrier pigeon for all it cares, *as long as it follows the TCP protocol*. I don't see how reverse-engineering the IOCP library has anything to do with the question.

Comment: @Thomas, ok, then I have totally misunderstood the question and this answer. Still not sure...  maybe this is related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10978765/connecting-to-iocp-server-in-java-android

Comment: @Prof.Falken - IOCP is just one way of using the sockets API in an asynchronous and efficient manner on Windows. As long as the server is using TCP/IP then the clients can use any language or technology that supports TCP/IP. It's nothing like saying "CORBA is just TCP", CORBA is an object model and wire protocol that may use TCP/IP as a lower level communications channel; just as DCOM may use TCP/IP as a lower level communications channel. There's absolutely no comparison with using IOCP.

Answer (score 0):

For first question,yes you can use any language as long as you use TCP/IP protocol.

For second question,my solution is,create an stop event for iocp,and every once a while,send a little package to client,if client does not reply this package,set the stop event up,and release the connection for the client